# Puppeteer pegar dados do submit

Tags: javascript, front-end, pupeteer

O objetivo é ter um simples html com uma input de texto e quando o usuario dar submit no input com o nome de usuário do instagram, o puppeteer receber a url `('https://instagram.com/${username}')` porém estou a dias tentando passar esse ${username} do frontend para o backend e não consigo.

**HTML**

```
<form name="" action="">
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
        <input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="submitName()">
</form>
<script src="./scripts/index.js"></script>
```

**index.js**

```
const ig = require('./instagram');
async function submitName(){
  const inputUsername = document.querySelector('#username');
  const username = await inputUsername.value
  await ig.inicialize(`https://instagram.com/${username}`)
  console.log(`https://instagram.com/${username}`);
};
```

**instagram.js**

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

    const instagram = {
        browser: null,
        page: null,
    
        inicialize: async (url) => {
            instagram.browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
            instagram.page = await instagram.browser.newPage();
            await instagram.page.goto(url)
    }
}
        
module.exports = instagram;
```

Alguém sabe o que estou fazendo de errado? sei que tenho que executar o node instagram.js, porém não tem como executar sem ter a url, ja estou perdido...

Comment: olha, ate onde eu sei, para rodar o puppeteer tem que usar o node. Desse modo que voce que fez o formulario acredito que nao vai rodar o seu robo do instagram. Minha sugestão: crie um servidor com express e uma rota simples, e passe por post ou get a url digitada pelo usuario. Depois e so passar a url para a função que roda o robo e pronto.